# How to insert and synchronize git?

Tags: git

I have an extremely strange task.

Previous coder was bad and did an ugly thing: he tracked his work at git, but moved files to the server via FileZilla (FTP client), so I have a problem. How can I synchronize an existing code both at the local machine and the server?

I moved current .git folder to the project but now I have many uncommitted and unstaged changes.

What is the best strategy for synchronization and git insertion to this server folder?

Comment: If he worked in git, but copied files to the server, does that mean the git repository has the latest changes and there is no addition in the server? Or has there been development separately on the server too?

Comment: check these out - http://smallbusiness.chron.com/synchronize-filezilla-47982.html https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=27984 http://superuser.com/questions/123052/keeping-local-windows-folder-in-sync-with-remote-ftp-folder-in-real-time